# pegar os ultimos 2 tokens de uma variavel em Batch

Tags: batch, cmd

eu preciso pegar **os ultimos 2 tokens de uma variavel** em batch

a variavel é

```
Rastreando a rota para user722-PC [192.168.1.106]
```

a saida que eu preciso é uma variavel contendo

```
user722-PC
```

e outra contendo

```
[192.168.1.106]
```

e não, não posso usar

```
for /f "tokens=5,6 delims= " %%a in ("%variable%") do set host=%%a & set ip=%%b
echo %ip% %host%
```

porque neste caso estou especificando os token 5,6 e oque quero afzer é pegar os ultimos 2 tokens dinamicamente, entao não posso especificar nenhum numero de token manualmente

// desse jeito da pra pegar somente o ultimo token, considerando que o delimitador é espaço, e não há como alterar o delimitador

```
FOR %%a in (%variable%) do set lastPart=%%a
ECHO %lastPart%
```

Comment: queria uma explicação em portugues, ainda estou confuso https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46943039/get-last-2-tokens-from-a-variable-in-batch/46943397#46943397

Comment: parece que sim...

Answer (score 1):

> **Seria isso?**

```bat
@echo off
set "_var_=Rastreando a rota para user722-PC [192.168.1.106]" 
for /f "tokens=5,6* delims=^ " %%i in ('echo/%_var_%') do echo/%%i %%j
```

> **saida:**

```bat
user722-PC [192.168.1.106]
```